# change two icons when the mouse is over button

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my `Button`, that holds two images and `TextBlock`, docked in panel - 
how to change the sources of this images when the mouse is over the button?
Is it possible to do with trigger logic?

```
<Button x:Name="proudlyPostedBtn" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0"  Height="20" Width="300"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Focusable="False">
   <DockPanel>
      <Image Source="{StaticResource HeaderImageSource1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Hello world</TextBlock>
      <Image Source="{StaticResource HeaderImageSource2}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
   </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

I am not using ControlTemplate as in suggested question

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a image button that change the image when mouse over button WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657048/how-to-make-a-image-button-that-change-the-image-when-mouse-over-button-wpf)

Comment: another possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502914/how-do-i-change-an-image-on-hover-over-in-wpf  (and the solution seems to fit to your question, replace the image with triggered styles)