# "MouseOver" in Labels and Buttons in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to Xaml but I have been taking advantage of the WPF for a while. For that reason I have made the below method which I use to change the image of a label or button anytime I wanna implement a mouse over or mouse leave event.

```
public void SImpleImageHadler(dynamic thing, String Path) {
        ImageBrush IB = new ImageBrush();
        IB.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Path, UriKind.Absolute));
        thing.Background = IB;
}
```

I would like to know how I can do this purely using xaml so that I wouldn't have to make a lot of event handlers for each of my UI elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the style triggers for your button you can put this type of code to change properties. To see a image specific example check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271916/wpf-button-mouseover-image) question.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271980/1483002) answer is an image example:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProjectName;component/Images/MyImage.jpg" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into attached properties if you want to encapsulate such stuff for many different types of Buttons/Labels.

The final result should look like this:

```
<Button
   ns2:MouseOverBackgroundChanger="YourURL"
/>

<Label
  ns2:MouseOverBackgroundChanger="YourUrl2"
/>
```

This site has everything you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx (Attached Properties Overview)