# Issue with Button Hover Image in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am attempting to change a button image when there is a mouse hover over in and I cant seem to get it to work. I have accomplished to get the blue hue to not appear when the button is hovered over but cannot get the image to change now. I have read numerous posts on it here and followed other examples but cant make it work. When I use the code below and hover over the button the image remains the same and doesn't change to the new one specified. Thoughts?

Blue Hue Removal

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNoHighlighting" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Button Hover Image

```
<Button x:Name="btnCloseApp" 
        Click="Application_Close"  
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleNoHighlighting}">

        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/BTN_Close.png"/>
        </Button.Background>

        <Button.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="BackgroundButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/BTN_Close_Hover.png" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check for the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271916/wpf-button-mouseover-image. Best regards,

Comment: Perfect! I actually saw this one before but mistook it for another example I saw. To keep source code down is there a way to implement this for different buttons with different button images or will I need to repeat this for each button I want to do this on?

Comment: I am glad it works for you. In case you have more questions I would recommend to post them separately. My best,