# Static resource for Setter Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my `Style` in App.xaml:

```
        <Style x:Key="numButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Image x:Name="img" Style="{DynamicResource imgDefault}"></Image>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="img" Value="img/1_push.png"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="imgDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/0.png"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have multiple buttons as numbers (0-9) and I want to use one style for all of the to avoid more text typing. Currently I am able to change each button's default background like this:

```
                <Button Name="btn1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource numButton}" Foreground="White">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="imgDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/1.png"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
```

So now I want to know is it possible to change `Value="img/1_push.png"` in App.xaml for each button when it's pressed? For example when `2` is pressed I want it's background to be `2_push.png`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12271980/692829) answer, you only need to replace `IsMouseOver` with `IsPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create custom Button class with two dependency properties:

**ImageButton.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class ImageButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultImageProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultImage", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageButton));

        public Uri DefaultImage
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(DefaultImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DefaultImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PressedImage", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageButton));

        public Uri PressedImage
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(PressedImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PressedImageProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                    <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding DefaultImage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/0.png, TargetNullValue=img/0.png}" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="img" Value="{Binding PressedImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/1_push.png, TargetNullValue=img/1_push.png}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<local:ImageButton x:Name="btn1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White"
                       DefaultImage="img/1.png" PressedImage="2_push.png"/>
```

This is a much more cleaner and flexible approach.

Comment: You could also use attached dependency properties, you don't necessarily need a custom `Button` class.

Comment: Unlike a control attached properties have no default control template or implicit style.

Comment: @mm8 in my MainWindow.xaml it says `The namespace prefix "local" is not defined`. Do I need to create `public class ImageButton` inside of my MainWindow.cs?

Comment: Nvm. I just added `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFApplication"` and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @mm8 I just noticed that background is not changing. Whichever button I press it's changing background to `1_push.png`

Comment: Make sure that the path of the PressedImage property is correct, e.g.: PressedImage="img/2_push.png". Then it should work. It certainly does for me :)

Comment: I event tested `DefaultImage="img/2.png" PressedImage="2.png"`. When I press it still shows `1_push.png` for all buttons.

Comment: This means that the path is invalid. Try /img/2_push.png with a leading / and make sure that you actually have a file called "2_push.png" in a folder called "img" at the root folder of your project.