# Setting a background image for a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouse, controltemplate

Really stupid question but I have set a background image for my button via XAML. But when I run the application and hover over it changes to default looking skin.

I can't work out how to do a Mouse over?

```
<Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Canvas.Left="93" Canvas.Top="93" Width="183" 
            Click="button_Click" Height="84" FontFamily="Showcard Gothic" Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/BlueButton.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271916/wpf-button-mouseover-image?answertab=active#tab-top. And next time remember to use a good title, and not generic.

Comment: Yeah, this is the button chrome used by the button default control template that messes with the background on mouse over. You basically need to define your own control template for the button to get rid of that, as pointed out by Baro...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271916/wpf-button-mouseover-image?answertab=active#tab-top). Consider using `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` for the `Border` inside the `Template`, so it update the `Background` of the `Border` when `Button`'s Background changed.

```
<Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Canvas.Left="93" Canvas.Top="93" Width="183" 
        Click="button_Click"   Height="84" FontFamily="Showcard Gothic" Cursor="Hand" 
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/5.png" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> <!--Consider this-->
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/5.png" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```